# Does Sys Prefs > Software Upgrade > "Automatically keep my Mac up to date" automatically install Catalina on a Mac running Mojave?

Tags: macos, mac, mojave, software-update, catalina

Given a Mac running [macOS Mojave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave), does turning on the checkbox "Automatically keep my Mac up to date" in [`System Preferences`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Preferences) > `Software Update` mean that [Catalina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/macOS_Catalina) will automatically be installed?

I want only minor updates and security patches to be installed automatically, not the major OS upgrades. I do not yet want to step up to Catalina.

[image: screenshot of Sys Prefs > Software Upgrade > "Automatically keep my Mac up to date" panel]

I found this useless [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/get-macos-updates-mchlpx1065/mac) about the Advanced panel that simply repeats the text of the checkboxes’ labels as a pseudo-explanation. (Tip: Click the `Helpful?` > `No` button at bottom of that page as feedback to Apple.)

[image: screenshot of Sys Prefs > Software Upgrade > "Automatically keep my Mac up to date" > Advanced panel]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367995/how-to-block-updates-to-mac-os-x-catalina/367996#comment496524_367996 exact same question in comments.

Comment: @ankii Actually, nothing on that page explains exactly what the options in "Advanced" means. Neither does the [lousy Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/get-macos-updates-mchlpx1065/mac).

Comment: yes, I linked it here to notify that user in future, if you accept answers. There is no important info there. Help page says "Automatically keep my Mac up to date= 
Select this tickbox to have your Mac install updates automatically." https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mchla7037245/10.14/mac/10.14.5

Comment: Apple generally distinguishes between up**dates** (minor version changes, like 10.14.0 to 10.14.6, security updates, etc) and up**grades** (major version changes, like Mojave (10.14.x) to Catalina (10.15.x). As far as I know, the automatic update feature only does up**dates**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it does not.

I have Mojave and it installed several updates yesterday automatically but a major system upgrade has to be authorized manually. So it is telling me it is there and available but not installing until I give permission.

Edit: I have the updates checked in the advanced panel and it did not install Catalina. See:

[image]

I suggest it is a question of understanding: "install system updates" is relevant to the current system not changing to a new system

Comment: If that is so, then what is the "Install macOS updates" option in the Advanced panel?

Comment: @BasilBourque I suggest it is a question of understanding: "install system updates" is relevant to the current system not changing to a **new** system.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying it out now to verify myself.

Answer (score 0):

macOS Catalina will appear as a software update in System Preferences once you have downloaded it from the Mac App Store. Mojave will not install Catalina automatically if you have enabled automatic updates.