# How do I stop Big Sur from installing on my computer?

Tags: catalina, big-sur

I have Catalina running on a 16" MacBook Pro.

I do not want to upgrade to Big Sur until next July.
Is there a way to do that?

**Responding to BMike:**

Two days before Big Sur dropped I set Software Update as follows:

[image]

On the day Big Sur dropped I got the update message and I told it to remind me tomorrow.

Today I tried the sudo command and got this:

[image]

I am going to leave this open for another day, but at the moment it looks like the answer is "You can't"

Comment: See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/367995/88313) that's about auto-updating to Catalina. Try the steps, they should still work for Big Sur but I haven't tried them.

Comment: There is a difference between an *update* of an existing operating system (e.g. 10.15.5 -> 10.15.6) and an *upgrade* from one version of the operating system to another (e.g. 10.15.X -> 11.0.1). (This was true for "minor" version upgrades, such as 10.14.X -> 10.15.X). I'm unaware of any way to make Big Sur be installed short of you explicitly clicking "Upgrade Now".

Comment: Thanks for the extra context - I've edited my answer. The command to block won't work until such time as you see it listed as ready for a command line option. See the tool Big Sur Blocker if you need to be sure you block it before it's advertised.

Answer (score 19):

Disable the **Automatically keep my Mac up to date** check box.

[image]

Use the second “more info ...” blue link to get security updates until you are ready to take the invitation to upgrade. It’s listed below the **Other Updates** text in the middle of the window.  If you [like the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372687/5472) you can pick and choose from any or all available update(s) and also suppress them by name.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --ignore "macOS Big Sur"
```

Please [read this entire article before trying `sudo` for the first time](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/enter-administrator-commands-apd5b0b6259-a7d4-4435-947d-0dff528912ba/mac), you could delete all your documents and photos with a syntax error or bad copy/paste of a good command. If you use Time Machine, one `sudo` alone won’t delete your backups.

- https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2020/11/12/preventing-the-macos-big-sur-upgrade-advertisement-from-appearing-in-the-software-update-preference-pane-on-macos-catalina/

The article above explains the down side of trying to block Big Sur before it's advertised and the error message you will see in that case. A more invasive solution would be to use an MDM product to block the actual installer. Or compile an app like the following open-source tool which anyone can compile with a free AppleID and free version of Xcode.

- https://github.com/hjuutilainen/bigsurblocker

Comment: The [article you referenced](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/enter-administrator-commands-apd5b0b6259-a7d4-4435-947d-0dff528912ba/mac) has inspired a [new Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406429/why-can-i-not-use-sudo-as-a-standard-user-in-macos/406430#406430) :)

Comment: The ability to ignore specific updates via terminal has been deprecated (and did not work for the last couple of months for me as I tried to avoid Catalina)

Comment: I am getting following message: `Software Update can only ignore updates that are eligible for installation.
If the label provided to ignore is not in the above list, it is not eligible
to be ignored.

Ignoring software updates is deprecated.
The ability to ignore individual updates will be removed in a future release of macOS.
`

Comment: Two days before Big Sur dropped I made the following settings to  software update .

Comment: I’ll make a [chat] room for support on Big Sur later in the week. We are calling this and it’s confirmed Apple is warning people but we believe Catalina and below can still use this despite the warnings... ask for help on main for now...

Comment: Big Sur Blocker, linked at the end, seems like the most sure fire way to make sure Big Sur is blocked. I'm not sure what the paragraph about compiling is about, it appears to be available as a binary at that Github link.

Comment: I just assume people like to compile open source - Feel free to edit the post to a download link you trust @Wowfunhappy Thanks for pointing out it’s downloadable.

Comment: I not happy with totally or partially disabling automatic updates, but I do want to block the Big Sur upgrade (and not see a red badge on the Software Update app).  The sudo command worked for me when I ran it just now (2020/11/17).  This is after the upgrade has been advertised.

Answer (score 0):

If you have unchecked all the options in the Software Update > Advanced dialog, as shown in your question, and unchecked "**Automatically keep my Mac up to date**", then OS upgrade and updates will not install unless you manually do so.

In fact "**Install MacOS updates**" is the critical setting. I bypassed Catalina entirely on one of my Macs.

I would recommend turning on "**install system data files and security updates**", as this will update the built-in malware database and patch other security flaws.