# Why can I not use `sudo` as a `Standard` user in macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, sudo, documentation

I do most of the "work" I do on my Mac as a `Standard` user (Apple parlance for an *unprivileged* user). I also frequently use the CLI (`zsh` mostly now) via the `Terminal` app. I use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) as a *package manager*, and various utilities such as `find`, `rsync`, `launchctl`, `ip`, `mount`, `log`, `softwareupdate`, etc etc etc. As it frequently happens, something I am trying to do from the CLI requires *privilege elevation* via the `sudo` command.

However: According to [this document](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/enter-administrator-commands-apd5b0b6259-a7d4-4435-947d-0dff528912ba/mac), it seems that Apple does not support the use of `sudo` by `Standard` users:

> Only administrator users can use sudo. If you’re not logged in as an administrator, you can do so by entering the following command, where **adminUsername** is the name of an administrator user:

> ***% su adminUsername***

This seems clumsy and inconvenient: `su` and then `sudo`. It is also at odds with the way `sudo` works on other platforms I use. Of course macOS requires Admin user authentication to perform some tasks in the GUI, but this is *generally* not the way that `sudo` operates; i.e. ***any*** user may be granted privileges to perform specified tasks by the Admin user for the system.

I won't ask "why" Apple does it this way as that can only be an *opinion* here, but I will ask if there is a *work-around* - can `sudo` on macOS be made to work as it does on other platforms?

Comment: Well done! “Given Apple has done X, how can I do Y?” type questions are some that I love to ask and answer and learn. It calls out for experience and explanation as opposed to just complaining or Monday morning quatrterbacks...

Comment: @bmike: Oh, please make no mistake - there is some complaining here :)  Chief complaint is that open source projects with zero labor costs and bank balances do a vastly superior job to the world's largest corporation (by market cap). This strikes me as disrespect for their customers.

Comment: I love withering criticism when it’s done well. Just complaining isn’t productive, complaining well is the best kind.

Comment: I think you're approaching this as someone with *experience* in system administration and Apple is putting together a standard set of user profiles that can be understood by their *very broad and diverse customer base* who span the gamut from expert kernel developers to folks who can barely get iTunes working. "Standard User" is not "Apple parlance" as Windows uses it as well.

Comment: A "standard user" could be a student or a task worker who should have no rights whatsoever.  This generic user profile allows a non technical person to be up and running  quickly and be assured that the system is secure.  If you, an experienced user, needs more granular access and permission profiles, the ability to create them exists - you just need to create and administer them.

Comment: Hey @Allan I’m not so sure anyone’s trying to be mean spirited here or anyone needs to change things... I think Seamus and I are of a similar mind - we will complain about how _we_feel about things once we back it up with some facts or at least an explanation. It’s ok to say, I disagree with that feeling or don’t share it, but probably better to not tell others to re-evaluate things.

Comment: Is it possible to block people on SE?

Comment: @Seamus no. But moderators can set up private chats if needed. Gonna put a hold on comments here for a bit and make some light edits.

Comment: The voting on this question, and an answer below is interesting. As of today, there have been **6 votes** cast on the question, and **8 votes** cast on the answer. Everyone will draw their own conclusions from this, but for me, the divergence suggests that criticism of Apple is not well received here.

Answer (score 9):

`sudo` on macOS ***does*** work as it does on other platforms - at least through macOS 10.15.6:

If you, as a "Standard" user, want or need privileges to perform certain tasks, those privileges may be granted by the Admin user in the `sudoers` file. If you are both the Admin user, and the unprivileged StandardJoe user, this becomes a bit *trite*, but here's how it works:

```
% su AdminUser
# authentication, and then:
Adminuser %
```

Now, as `Adminuser`, use the `visudo` command to edit the `sudoers` file:

```
Adminuser % sudo visudo
```

This will open the `sudoers` file in an editor (perhaps `pico`). This next step is **not** the way things would be done on a multi-user system, but in this case as there's only one user, and we're trying to make a point, we'll abandon convention & ['throw caution to the wind'](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+caution+to+the+wind) :)

Add the following line to the `sudoers` file:

```
StandardJoeUser ALL = (ALL) /usr/sbin/visudo
```

Save the file, and exit the editor. Then `exit` the Admin user's shell:

```
Adminuser % exit
%
```

What have we just done? We have given your StandardJoeUser user permission to make any changes he wishes to the `sudoers` file. With that permission, you - as StandardJoeUser - can add the privileges you need - or `ALL` the privileges available to the Admin user if you choose.

To continue as StandardJoeUser, we'll now grant him the same privileges under `sudo` as the Admin user has:

```
% sudo visudo
# authenticate with StandardJoeUser's password
```

Again, the `sudoers` file is opened in the editor. This time, add the following line just below the one added previously:

```
StandardJoeUser ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

Once again, save & exit. Now - StandardJoeUser can `sudo` anything - same as the Admin user. There is no need to change to the Admin user (`su`); you may `sudo` under your Standard user's credentials.

Debating the *wisdom* of this change could be classified as *opinion* under SE rules, so I'll stop here. The answer to the question should be clear enough now: **Yes, `sudo` on macOS *does* work the same as on other platforms; it seems the [document you referenced](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/enter-administrator-commands-apd5b0b6259-a7d4-4435-947d-0dff528912ba/mac) could be classified as *inaccurate* under some definition of the word.**

Comment: This example is assumes only a binary condition - either no access or full access.  This is not the case.  There are many points between these two extremes  here that user roles and permissions can be defined through the use of ACL's, groups, etc.  `sudo` is just one tool in this tool box.

Comment: @Allan: Your comment reflects a misunderstanding of the question, and fails to appreciate the fact that the example serves only to illustrate how the OP can utilize `sudo` as a "Standard" user in macOS. This answer was never intended to address all the points in between.